# Does the returning clause always execute first?

Tags: postgresql

I have a many-to-many relation representing `container`s holding `item`s.

I have a primary key row_id in the table.

I insert four rows: `(container_id, item_id) values (1778712425160346751, 4)`. These rows will be identical except the aforementioned unique row_id.

I subsequently execute the following query:

```
delete from contains
    where item_id = 4 and
    container_id = '1778712425160346751' and
    row_id =  
        (
            select max(row_id) from contains
            where container_id = '1778712425160346751' and
            item_id = 4
        )
    returning
        (
            select count(*) from contains
            where container_id = '1778712425160346751' and
            item_id = 4
        );
```

Now I expected to get 3 returned from this query, but I got a 4. Getting a 4 is the desired behavior, but it is not what was expected.

My question is: **can I always expect that the `returning` clause executes before the delete, or is this an idiosyncrasy of certain versions or specific software?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of a query in `returning` section is allowed but not documented. For [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html):

> output_expression
>
> An expression to be computed and returned by the DELETE command after each row is deleted. The expression can use any column names of the table named by table_name or table(s) listed in USING. Write * to return all columns.

It seems logical that the query sees the table in a state before deleting, as the statement is not completed yet.

```
create temp table test as 
select id from generate_series(1, 4) id;

delete from test
returning id, (select count(*) from test);

 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     4
  2 |     4
  3 |     4
  4 |     4
(4 rows)
```

The same concerns `update`:

```
create temp table test as 
select id from generate_series(1, 4) id;

update test
set id = id+ 1
returning id, (select sum(id) from test);

 id | sum 
----+-----
  2 |  10
  3 |  10
  4 |  10
  5 |  10
(4 rows)
```

Comment: I want to point out that if I do an update it seems the returned value is the value **after** the update. Insert comment about castles made of sand...

Comment: The values of deleted or updated columns are always up-to-date, we are talking about a **subquery** in `returning` clause.

Comment: Ah I see, if I do `returning select updatedColumn from table` it gets the old value, if i do `returning updatedColumn` it gets the updated value. That's a sensible result.